# Wrapping "osascript -e" to multiple lines in bash?

Tags: applescript, bash

Is it possible to wrap a long "osascript -e" command across multiple lines in Bash?

For instance:

```
echo $(osascript -e text returned of '(display dialog "Enter your email address:" default answer "" with title "Question" with icon POSIX file "/Application/Mail.app/Contents/Resources/ApplicationIcon.icns" buttons {"OK"} default button "OK")')
```

like

```
echo $(osascript -e text returned of '(
    display dialog "Enter your email address:" default answer ""
    with title "Question" buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
    with icon POSIX file "/Application/Mail.app/Contents/Resources/ApplicationIcon.icns"
    )'
)
```

I have tried several things, but all attempts end in syntax errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the regular AppleScript [Continuation Character](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_lexical_conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH214-SW9)?

Comment: @red_menace Sorry, it was just my ipad’s broswer. Works fine on mac

Comment: I will give that a try and see what happens. Thanks @red_menace!

Comment: @red_menace i think you should post your comment as an answer so that this question can be answered

Comment: I agree, that worked as expected. Thanks @red_menace